# How can I set up ALE to be opt-in?

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm trying to use ALE for auto-formatting for one specific language, however it has everything turned on for all languages by default and I can't figure out how to configure it so that it's disabled for everything except what I explicitly tell it to.

I've tried using `g:ale_pattern_options`, I've tried setting `g:ale_enabled = 0` and then setting `b:ale_enabled = 1` in the filetype plugin but then it just doesn't run at all.

Comment: Your approach should work—of course, there was one variable that can control what linters are enabled, and you could use that to disable everything. But i would have tried your approach first... what does ALEInfo say?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ALEInfo says `g:ale_enabled = 0` (newline) `b:ale_enabled = 1` but it doesn't work. I've since read somewhere that disabling ALE globally like that can mess things up, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `g:ale_linters_explicit` option

https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/doc/ale.txt#L1317